# Gstreamer Mac OS X udpsink error

Tags: macos, gstreamer

I’m trying to stream audio in Mac OS X but I keep getting this error:

```
gst-launch osxaudiosrc ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink port=10001 host=192.168.2.10

Setting pipeline to PAUSED …
ERROR: Pipeline doesn’t want to pause.
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0: Could not get/set settings from/on resource.
Additional debug info:
gstmultiudpsink.c(804): gst_multiudpsink_configure_client (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSink:udpsink0:
Could not set TTL socket option (22): Invalid argument
Setting pipeline to NULL …
Freeing pipeline …
```

This works in Windows replacing `osxaudiosrc` with `autoaudiosrc`, anyone know what's the problem?

thanks

Comment: This is happening to me also on similar cases: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4649925/207894 Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8):

You might be missing the **gst-ffmpeg** plugin. I'm saying this because [I'd encoutered a similiar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649925/convert-video-to-webm-using-gstreamer).

You can install it using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) (preferred) or [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/).

Homebrew command: `brew install gst-ffmpeg`

I would also suggest installing the other packages. This command will install GStreamer and all it's packages: `brew install gstreamer gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good gst-plugins-bad gst-plugins-ugly gst-ffmpeg`.

Use `brew search gst` to search for other packages that you might need concerning GStreamer.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in the udpsink/multiudpsink code related to IPV6 enabled systems and socket creation.

If you are coding up your pipeline in C you can bypass this by manually creating the socket to use and using that for the sink like so.

```
my_sink = gst_element_make_from_uri(GST_URI_SINK, "udp://233.34.28.1:31337", NULL);
int my_tx_socket;
my_tx_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP)
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(my_sink), “sockfd”, my_tx_socket, NULL);
```

If you were just going to use it using gst-launch I'm afraid that you will have to edit your way through multiudpsink.c until you figure out how to bypass thus.

Answer (score 0):

This bug has been fixed in GStreamer-1.0 so install (e.g. `port install gstreamer1-gst-plugins-good`) and run - making sure you use the v1 pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 osxaudiosrc ! audioresample ! audioconvert ! alawenc ! rtppcmapay ! udpsink port=10001 host=192.168.2.10
```